# Entropy output is NaN for some class solutions and not others

Tags: r, entropy

I am running a latent class analysis in R and using the Entropy function. I wanted to understand why in the output, it produces a result for lower nclasses and then NaN for higher Nclasses.

I am a beginner to the software!

For reference here, is the output and code:

```
> entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
> error_prior <- entropy(France_2class$P) # Class proportions
> error_post <- mean(apply(France_2class$posterior, 1, entropy))
> R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post) / error_prior
> R2_entropy
[1] 0.8121263
> 
> entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
> error_prior <- entropy(France_3class$P) # Class proportions
> error_post <- mean(apply(France_3class$posterior, 1, entropy))
> R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post) / error_prior
> R2_entropy
[1] 0.8139903
> 
> entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
> error_prior <- entropy(France_4class$P) # Class proportions
> error_post <- mean(apply(France_4class$posterior, 1, entropy))
> R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post) / error_prior
> R2_entropy
[1] NaN
> 
> entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
> error_prior <- entropy(France_5class$P) # Class proportions
> error_post <- mean(apply(France_5class$posterior, 1, entropy))
> R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post) / error_prior
> R2_entropy
[1] NaN
> 
> entropy<-function (p) sum(-p*log(p))
> error_prior <- entropy(France_6class$P) # Class proportions
> error_post <- mean(apply(France_6class$posterior, 1, entropy))
> R2_entropy <- (error_prior - error_post) / error_prior
> R2_entropy
[1] NaN
```

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: did you check the class of field, you are trying to find entropy? Entropy works only for numeric/factors type object, if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem comes from the definition of `entropy`. More precisely, if `0` is contained in `p`, then you will obtain `NaN`, e.g.,

```
> entropy(p1)
[1] 1.279854

> entropy(p2)
[1] NaN

> entropy(p3)
[1] 0.5004024
```

---

To fix it, you can add `na.omit` to function `entropy` like below

```
entropy<-function(p) sum(na.omit(-p*log(p)))
```

then you can see

```
> entropy(p1)
[1] 1.279854

> entropy(p2)
[1] 0.5004024

> entropy(p3)
[1] 0.5004024
```

**DATA**

```
p1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4)
p2 <- c(0,0.2,0.8)
p3 <- c(0.2,0.8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, that sorted the issue!