# Entropy calculation gives NaN - is applying na.omit a valid tweak?

Tags: r, statistics, entropy

By definition, the entropy is defined as:

```
entropy <- function (p) sum(-p * log(p))
```

I'm performing LCA using the **poLCA** package and trying to calculate entropy, which for some of my models are outputting `NaN`.

```
error_prior <- entropy(lca2$P) # Class proportions model 2
error_post <- mean(apply(lca2$posterior, 1, entropy), na.rm = TRUE)
results[2,8] <- round(((error_prior - error_post) / error_prior), 3)
```

From the answer to this question: [Entropy output is NaN for some class solutions and not others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61302401/4891738), I learnt that it is caused by zeros in `p` and it can be resolved by adding `na.omit` to the function as follows:

```
entropy <- function (p) sum(na.omit(-p * log(p)))
```

My question is - is this technical tweak mathematically valid without affecting the integrity of the calculation?

In my case, around 1/3 of the values in `p` are zeros. I'm really unsure if I should use `na.omit` or find another way to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid, but not transparent at first glance. The reason is that the mathematical limit of *xlog(x)* as *x -> 0* is 0 (we can prove this using L'Hospital Rule). In this regard, the most robust definition of the function should be

```
entropy.safe <- function (p) {
  if (any(p > 1 | p < 0)) stop("probability must be between 0 and 1")
  log.p <- numeric(length(p))
  safe <- p != 0
  log.p[safe] <- log(p[safe])
  sum(-p * log.p)
}
```

But simply dropping `p = 0` cases gives identical results, because the  result at `p = 0` is 0 and contributes nothing to the sum anyway.

```
entropy.brutal <- function (p) {
  if (any(p > 1 | p < 0)) stop("probability must be between 0 and 1")
  log.p <- log(p)
  ## as same as sum(na.omit(-p * log.p))
  sum(-p * log.p, na.rm = TRUE)
}

## p has a single 0
( p <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1) )
#[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
entropy.brutal(p)
#[1] 2.455935
entropy.safe(p)
#[1] 2.455935

## half of p are zeros
p[1:5] <- 0
p
#[1] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
entropy.brutal(p)
#[1] 1.176081
entropy.safe(p)
#[1] 1.176081
```

In conclusion, we can use either `entropy.brutal` or `entropy.safe`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed response... So in the case of my analyses where there are nearly always some probabilities that equal 0, I should default to entropy function containing na.omit?